# How to manually invoke an event?

Tags: c#, events

I have the following line in C#:

```
_timer.ElapsedTick += _somefunction1;
_timer.ElapsedTick += _somefunction2;
_timer.ElapsedTick += _somefunction3;
```

How to invoke all methods subscribed to _timer.ElapsedTick without specifying the _somefunction ? Somewhere along this pseudo-line

```
invoke(_timer.ElapsedTick);
```

Comment: your question should A: not include it's own answer and B: don't use "UPDATE" tags: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/127655/316262

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Can it be done using conventional C#? No ([as previously stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8734811/635634)). But using reflection it is possible. Here is some tested code based on the answer to [this MSDN forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/44b0d573-5c53-47b0-8e85-6056cbae95b0):

```
class InvokeFromMe
{
    public event EventHandler RaiseMe;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var fromMe = new InvokeFromMe();

        fromMe.RaiseMe += fromMe_RaiseMe;
        fromMe.RaiseMe += fromMe_RaiseMe1;
        fromMe.RaiseMe += fromMe_RaiseMe2;

        FireEvent(fromMe, "RaiseMe", null, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    static void fromMe_RaiseMe(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Event Handler 0 Raised");
    }
    static void fromMe_RaiseMe1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Event Handler 1 Raised");
    }
    static void fromMe_RaiseMe2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Event Handler 2 Raised");
    }

    public static void FireEvent(object onMe, string invokeMe, params object[] eventParams)
    {
        MulticastDelegate eventDelagate =
              (MulticastDelegate)onMe.GetType().GetField(invokeMe,
               System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
               System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(onMe);

        Delegate[] delegates = eventDelagate.GetInvocationList();

        foreach (Delegate dlg in delegates)
        {
            dlg.Method.Invoke(dlg.Target, eventParams);
        }
    } 

}
```

**UPDATE**

I'm not familiar with the `System.Timer.Timer` class, so I'm not sure what is different from my provided example. You could perhaps try something like:

```
public static void FirePublicEvent(object onMe, string invokeMe, params object[] eventParams)
{
    MulticastDelegate eventDelagate =
          (MulticastDelegate)onMe.GetType().GetField(invokeMe,
           System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance |
           System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public).GetValue(onMe);

    Delegate[] delegates = eventDelagate.GetInvocationList();

    foreach (Delegate dlg in delegates)
    {
       dlg.Method.Invoke(dlg.Target, eventParams);
    }
}
```

Comment: The FireEvent is exactly what I am looking for, almost ! It is currently giving me a FieldInfo=null on the GetField. Am I missing a BindingFlag ? The target event is System.Timer.Timer.ElapsedTick . The somefunction methods are currently private, but I can change them to internals or public.

Comment: @JesonMartajaya - Do you mean `System.Timers.Timer.Elapsed`? This won't work if the event is private. The event handlers can be private though.

Comment: @JesonMartajaya - Can I see your call to `FireEvent`? As long as `onMe` is an instance of `System.Timer.Timer` then you should be passing 'ElapsedTick' for `invokeMe`. I'll also update my answer to cover the case where the event is `public`.

Comment: Yes, I mean System.Timers.Timer. The event name should be Elapsed too, instead of ElapsedTick. I corrected both of them, plus adding bindingFlags.Public. It still does not work. Here is my line: FireEvent(_timer, "Elapsed", null, ElapsedEventArgs.Empty);

Comment: I just added my code on the question post above. We are almost there !

Comment: @JesonMartajaya - For the `System.Timers.Timer` class you will need to invoke `FireEvent` like so: `FireEvent(fromMe, "onIntervalElapsed", this, null);`

Comment: The `e` parameter has to be null because `ElapsedEventArgs` doesn't have a public constructor and `ElapsedEventArgs.Empty` returns an `EventArgs`. You may be able to use Reflection to instantiate it too but I'd have to play with it in order to know for sure.

Comment: You are excellent! FireEvent(fromMe, "onIntervalElapsed", this, null); is the right answer.

Comment: Your answer is excellent! FireEvent(fromMe, "onIntervalElapsed", this, null) is the right answer. By the way, how do you come with "onIntervalElapsed" method name. I see it is not listed in Timer's metadata.

Comment: I took `System.dll` into ILSpy and reverse engineered the event. Tools like Reflector, ILSpy, and JustDecompile are absolute must-haves for the .NET developer toolbox.

Comment: This requires to know the field name that's backing the event (if there's one, that is).

Comment: I personally had to add `BindingFlags.NonPublic` in the second parameter of `GetField` for my use case and it worked! :D thanks! (Works in Unity for testing events of libraries I don't own) :)

Comment: IMHO, resorting to `Reflection` is a major *code smell*. I haven't thought through the details, but wouldn't it be cleaner to subclass `Timer`, and give that subclass a method that does the desired `invoke` of Timer's event handler?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Sure, that would work in this specific case but what if the event's owner is `sealed`? Besides, that's a lot of ceremony and now that subclass is *your* problem to maintain and test. It would be better yet to refactor the event handler's logic into another method that can be invoked directly and bypass the event system altogether.

Comment: `MulticastDelegate` can be obtained via simple casting **without any reflection**: `(MulticastDelegate)onMe.EventHandler` and that's it. Moreover, inside `InvokeFromMe` class even casting is not needed. Apart from that, very helpful answer, thank you.

Answer (score 26):

You can't invoke an event which is owned by another type.  An event can only be invoked from the inside of the class which declares it.

Comment: @JaredPar- Respectfully, I disagree.  The example I posted below works fine for me across classes.  Unless, of course, we are talking about *threads* rather than classes.  And, even then, it can work with some extra coding.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt yes but you're using reflection.  That can be used to get around a huge number of restrictions in both the CLR and C#.  In general I don't consider reflection to be a valid answer for "how can I do X"  It definitely works

Comment: Thanks JaredPar.  For my own education, why would my answer be invalid if it definitely works?

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt in *general* when answering a "how do you do this in C#" question I limit my answers to what can be done with the language without reflection / pinvoke / COM interop. Those are very often taboo within code bases and hence not generally *correct*. There are loads of things which are possible once you bring in reflection that simply can't be done with C# and often with good reason.  For example allowing you to invoke my event for me is dangerous. It could very easily break subtle guarantees my consumers depend on (book end events for example).

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt this is by no means a hard and fast rule nor is it universally agreed on.  It's my approach to answering questions.  If you look through my history I'm sure you can find loads of places where I decided to throw up a reflection answer.  I generally caveat my answer though with "not possible in vanilla C# but if you want to get your hands dirty" ...

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt I don't think you're answering the question that was asked. You aren't invoking all the listeners to the event, you're invoking a function by a string name.

Comment: @JaredPar- Ok, thanks.  I am using that in a few apps so I had better go research the possible pitfalls!  Thanks again.

Comment: @Smelch- Take a look at the pseudocode in the question.  I think that it is a fair assumption that the author knows how to iterate a loop  which is the other half to which you are referring.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt of course he could loop it, but he's saying he doesn't want to specify the functions to call, he wants to call the methods subscribed to the event. If he knew the string name of the functions, why would he even bother doing it that way, he would just call the functions.

Comment: @JaredPar Thank you for your comments. Would you please elaborate why "allowing you to invoke my event for me is dangerous" ?

Comment: @JesonMartajaya it's not always dangerous but often is. Consider the scenario where my type has a `Start` and `End` event. The guarantee I provide is I will raise them in order and a `Start` will always be accompanied by an `End`. Because I control events I can make this guarantee and another class can depend on this. If suddenly you can control my events then there is nothing stopping you from raising `End` before `Start` or `Start` with no end.  Additionally you raising the event could bypass my type setting the flag that I'm in the middle of a `Start` / `End` progression.  All very bad

Comment: @JaredPar-I see your point, but this could probably be said for alot of things in life: don't cross the street when there is oncoming traffic, for example.  Wouldn't this just be an issue of knowing what you have written in another class, or communicating with other developers?  Also, adding the correct documentation and expected parameters should act as a safety to some extent I would think.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt allowing someone else to invoke your events without your surrounding code is a violation of encapsulation. It's little different than allowing someone to invoke a private method.

Comment: @JaredPar-Well, regardless, your comments and dedication to this post taught me a few things and sparked thought and consideration of things I hadn't previously considered.  I thank you for that.  Please keep in mind, however, that it may be hard for a simpleton like me to wrap my brain around being told that something doesn't work when it actually does (albeit with drawbacks).  To that end, your patience was appreciated.  Thanks Jared!

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt you're right i should be more careful about saying it "doesn't work" when it's "it does work but you probably shouldn't be doing it".

Comment: @JaredPar- There ya go! Hey- now we've gotten some lawyering in for the day as well.  Cheers!

Answer (score 8):

well i end up here about searching how to simply start event, which is not having any custom args or anything. I know OP question is different! but i had like to share, i hope it helps someone.

Unsimplify version:

```
 var Handler = EventNameHere;
        if (Handler != null)
        {
            Handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
```

Simplify version:

```
 EventNameHere?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a function that runs them all:

```
public void RunAllFuncs()
{
   _somefunction1();
   _somefunction2();
   _somefunction3();
}
```

Comment: Definitely not what I am looking for. I have no reference to the somefunction methods other than view _timer.ElapsedTick.

Answer (score 2):

This is a work around, you can't loop through the Elapsed event.  But to invoke them all, let the timer do the work.  This code for System.Timer, not sure which timer you are using.

Presuming the timer is already enabled:

```
int interval = timer.Interval;
ElapsedEventHandler handler = null;
handler = (s,e) =>
{
    timer.Interval = interval; // put interval back to original value
    timer.Elapsed -= handler;
};
timer.Elapsed += handler;
timer.Interval = 1; // 1 millisecond, pretty much going to fire right now (as soon as you let it)
```

Something like that will fire the events, but your original interval will be restarted.  You may have to do some math in there if you want to keep the original tick pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably need to use InvokeMember:

```
public void GetMethod(string methodName){

            var args = new Object[] { [INSERT ARGS IF NECESSARY--SET TO NULL OTHERWISE] };
            try
            {
                var t = new [INSERT NAME OF CLASS THAT CONTAINS YOUR METHOD]();
                Type typeInfo = t.GetType();
                var result = typeInfo.InvokeMember(methodName, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, t, args);
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex;
            }
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
_timer.ElapsedTick += GetMethod("[INSERT METHOD NAME AS STRING]");
```

Be sure to include this:

```
using System.Reflection;
```

Good Luck!

Comment: To make it clearer, I am looking to manually raise the _timer.ElapsedTick event. From your proposed solution, do you think I can call GetMethod("_timer.ElapsedTick") ?

Comment: This is close but not quite. Your code here runs a method directly. You need to first get the field that represents the event on the type as a `MulticastDelegate`, then get its invocationlist and from there you can dynamically invoke each method individually. The answer to [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/44b0d573-5c53-47b0-8e85-6056cbae95b0) MSDN question shows how to do it.

Comment: You can call any *method* you like using "GetMethod", but just take a look at @JaredPar's comments as he has some reservations.  I have been using GetMethod successfully, but its hard to ignore a guy with 178k reputation when he warns against it.  Good luck!

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt - Yes you are right, you can invoke any *method* directly using the code you provided, but that isn't the question.

Comment: @M.Babcock- I see that you are very good at playing devil's advocate with my answer (which works).  Perhaps you could provide your own answer rather than pointing out that mine is incorrect/not answering the question?  We are software developers--not lawyers arguing semantics.  Let's help this guy out, shall we?

Comment: @M.Babcock- Nice--looks like you have almost gotten him there.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Based on [M.Babcock's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8735366/1438809) above, with some slight reflection method updates.

Replaced `GetField` with `GetTypeInfo` and `GetDeclaredField`, and `dlg.Method` with `dlg.GetMethodInfo`.

```
    using System.Reflection;

    ...

    public static void FireEvent(this object onMe, string invokeMe, params object[] eventParams)
    {
        TypeInfo typeInfo = onMe.GetType().GetTypeInfo();
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = typeInfo.GetDeclaredField(invokeMe);
        MulticastDelegate eventDelagate = (MulticastDelegate)fieldInfo.GetValue(onMe);

        Delegate[] delegates = eventDelagate.GetInvocationList();

        foreach (Delegate dlg in delegates)
        {
            dlg.GetMethodInfo().Invoke(dlg.Target, eventParams);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With .NET 6 (may work with other versions, too), the following generic method may be helpful. Like in other answers it uses reflection to invoke the EventHandler:

```cs
private void InvokeEvent<T, TEvent>(T target, string eventName, TEvent @event)
{
   // some reflection magic to fire an event from outside the target class:
   if(target == null)
   {
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(target));
   }
   Type targetType = target.GetType();
   FieldInfo? fi = targetType.GetField(eventName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance);
   if(fi != null)
   {
      EventHandler<TEvent>? eventHandler = fi.GetValue(target) as EventHandler<TEvent>;
      if(eventHandler != null)
      {
         eventHandler.Invoke(this, @event);
      }
   }
}
```

It can then be invoked like this:

```cs
const string eventName = nameof(Algorithm.Received);
DomainEvent @event = new DomainEvent(payload);
InvokeEvent(targetObject, eventName, @event);
```

Notes:

- The above code also works if multiple methods were added with `+=` to the event handler.
- If you want use this code in product you may want to consider more error handling such as parameter checking or throwing an exception if a specific event handler wasn't found.
- With each major version of .NET the code using reflection may need to be changed. As .NET 6 is cross-platform running on Windows, Linux, MacOS, etc. I suspect the likelihood of changes breaking the above code is reduced, although not zero.
- We are using this code in our automated test suite. In case the code using reflection does in fact change, we only need to change this one method.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answers before me, the following worked for me:

```
EventNameHere(null, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Answer (score -1):

Depending on the signature of the `ElapsedTick` event, you can fire the event by calling it like a method from inside the class in which it is declared. For example:

```
ElapsedTick(this, new EventArgs());
```

Comment: `EventArgs.Empty` is nice at it avoids an unnecessary allocation.  Also, you can't invoke an event from outside of the class like that.

Comment: I failed to mention that it is fired this way from inside the class. Also, using `EventArgs.Empty` is a nice touch.

Comment: I tried the following
    _timer.ElapsedTick(this, ElapsedEventArgs.Empty);
and it gives a compile-time error: 

'System.Timers.Timer' does not contain a definition for 'ElapsedTick' and no extension method 'ElapsedTick' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Timers.Timer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I don't see how this is an answer to the question (though I didn't downvote the answer). OP is *not* writing code *inside the class* (which in this case, is class `Timer`). So how does he make use of this suggestion? [Answering my own question: perhaps by subclassing `Timer`, and adding a public method that includes this line of code. This answer would need to show how to do so.]

Answer (score -1):

You can only call events from inside the class that declares it. If you wrote the timer class, you would invoke it like this:

```
this.ElapsedTick(this, eventArgs);
```

Outside the timer class you may do as follows to get similar behavior:

```
delegate void delegateSample(object sender, EventArgs e);

delegateSample d;
d += new delegateSample(_somefunction1);
d += new delegateSample(_somefunction2);
d(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

delegateSample should actually be the type of the ElapsedTick event, instead of declaring another delegate type. I just didn't know the name of that delegate. Just make sure you add each function the ElapsedTick event and the delegate variable you declare then you can call them all from the delegate outside the Timer class.

Comment: It is possible to call events across the class barrier in many instances. The trick is doing it across assemblies.