# How to automatically call Event in Windows Phone 8

Tags: events, windows-phone-8

How to automatically raise event in windows phone? For example, I have an element `<Image name = "image" .... />`. I want when a MainPage is loaded, it will automatically raise tap event on that element

Answer (score 1):

If you want to declare tap event dynamically (loads tap event on page load), You can declare it in following way. Here is your xaml.

```XAML
 <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
     <Image Name="image1"/>
 </Grid>
```

And in constructor,

```C#
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    image1.Tap += image1_Tap;
}
```

```C#
void image1_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    //Perform your action here
    //This method invokes only when you tap on image
}
```

Else, try the other way.

```C#
Loaded += (s, e) =>
{
    //Actions that are performed when image is tapped
}
```

Add above lines in your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This probably is not a good solution to whatever you are trying to accomplish. It can be done with reflection - [How to manually invoke an event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734700/how-to-manually-invoke-an-event) However I'd just extract your `Tap` event code to method and then call this method in your `Loaded` event and also `Tap` even.