# Forward tap event to UIElement behind another UIElement

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have a transparent Rectangle over other UIElements in a Grid. This rectangle should handle swipe gesture AND tap events. It should always handle swipe gestures but not tap events : under certain circumstances, I don't want this rectangle to handle the tap event but let the UIElements behind (like buttons) handle it.

If, under this circumstances, I set isTapEnabled to false, the tap is not handled neither by the rectangle nor by the buttons behind. If I set isHitTestVisible to false, the buttons behind handle well the tap events but the rectangle can't handle swipe gesture anymore...

Is there any solution, in my "tapped" event handler to just ignore the event according to the circumstances and let the buttons behind handle it ?

Comment: Well, balls.  If you register a handle for the tap event on the rectangle, and with a reference to the control behind it, can you invoke the tap manually?

Comment: The problem is that there are different buttons behind the rectangle which actually cover the whole screen. Invoking a tap manually was one of my ideas but I don't know how to do it, and especially how to do it at a specific position in order that the correct button can handle it...

Comment: You're going to have to do some research on how to invoke routed events.  I know you can do it via reflection (like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734700/how-to-manually-invoke-an-event) but you're probably not going to be able to do this in a phone app.  Might be some other method.  But that should get you started.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Will ! I will investigate if I can do something with the topic you indicated, and let you know...