# Fire system event to control other apps MediaPlayer

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm currently working on UWP project capable of controlling **other app's** background media player instance, i. e.:

```
MediaPlayer player = BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current;
```

As I found on [MSDN official documentation of MedaPlayer class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.playback.mediaplayer) - there is not any direct method of skipping song or moving to previous one.

I've been looking for a solution myself for few days, until i got onto something like this:
(FireEvent from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734700/how-to-manually-invoke-an-event) - modified one line to work on uwp)

```
private async void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MediaPlayer player = BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current;
    SystemMediaTransportControls d;
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { d = player.SystemMediaTransportControls; });

    await FireEvent(d, "ButtonPressed", new FakeEventArgs(SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Next));
}

public async Task FireEvent(object onMe, string invokeMe, params object[] eventParams)
{
    MulticastDelegate eventDelagate = (MulticastDelegate)onMe.GetType().GetField(invokeMe,
                                        BindingFlags.Instance |
                                        BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(onMe);

    Delegate[] delegates = eventDelagate.GetInvocationList();

    foreach (Delegate dlg in delegates)
    {
        dlg.DynamicInvoke(dlg.Target, eventParams);
    }
}
```

Although I made myself sure, that on my testing phone there is a music playing, after line defining eventDelegate I get:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in foo.exe
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there any other way of firing and event? Or even, some diffrent method of controlling other app's MediaPlayer?

**EDIT 1**
FakeEventArgs is made as equivalent of SystemMediaTransportControlsButtonPressedEventArgs, cause this class is not constructible, as here:

```
public sealed class FakeEventArgs
{
    SystemMediaTransportControlsButton Button = SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Pause;

    public FakeEventArgs (SystemMediaTransportControlsButton But)
    {
        Button = But;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a little unclear where you are getting the `NullReferenceException`, is it on the `eventDelagate` declaration, or on the `eventDelagate.GetInvocationList()` call? It would help if you included your stack trace in your question.

Comment: On the declaration, i can't show stack trace due to bugs in visual studio.

Comment: Are you verifying that you are actually passing a instance of an object in to the `FireEvent` call? Check that your variable `d` is not null before you attempt to perform an action on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues here.

Firstly, I was expecting the process isolation and security model to prevent any app (not just yours) from being able to do this kind of task. Controlling music playback is something that Metro/Modern/UWP apps have had very limited ability to do. Your can play your own music but you can't do a lot at a system level or influence another app that is playing music. If you're playing music you can pause it or if another app is playing music you can take control of playing music. As a general rule if you don't potentially want other apps doing potentially malicious things or if there's system UI to control something you can't do much with it yourself.

Anyway, your code looked interesting so I thought it was worth exploring. You may have found an interesting workaround.
Here are the specific issues I found.

1. The assigning of `d` doesn't need to be done async. For no reason that I can see, you create, and start, a new task to assign a value to `d`. As it doesn't need to be done asynchronously you could just do this as part of the normal flow of code in the click method.
2. The `FireEvent` method doesn't need to be async and you don't want it to return a Task, you just want it to run. The code will work and be simpler if the signature was `public void FireEvent(...`.
3. Now we get to why the code would never work. The type `SystemMediaTransportControls` doesn't have a Field called `"ButtonPressed"`. (Or any fields for that matter.) When the code `GetValue(onMe)` runs it will always through a `NullReferenceException`. From there on there's nothing for you to dynamically invoke.

I think you need to reconsider your app idea. It's not possible to arbitrarily control one UWP app from another UWP app unless the target app specifically exposes a way to do so.
The other question you referred to in your original question may work in a WPF app where the app model is less restrictive but I cannot guarantee it. You'd need to try this yourself.

Comment: Point 1 doesn't seem right: the task created is awaited for termination before `d` is actually used, so it should only be null if `player.SystemMediaTransportControls` is also null!

Comment: The code as is in the question won't actually even compile because you get a `Error CS0165 Use of unassigned local variable 'd'` error.

Comment: What a nice explanation! I'll try again with these advices - sorry for not responding, I thought a week off the topic may clear my mind.

Comment: Also Matt - the async keywords did not come without a reason. I just wanted to make sure that i wont occur 100th time error with threading.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be stuggling here, there's no way to control another applications audio. You can only use the transport controls.

```
 MediaPlayer player = BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current;
```

This line will shutdown the other applications background task that's playing music and create a new instance for you to use.

Comment: I'll try with `SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView();`, thanks.