# wrapping around an event inside another class c#

Tags: c#, events

I am writing a wrapper around a class that extends some parts of a 3th party class. It adds some functionality that was missing. And by keeping it a class I can use it in multiple projects.

However I wonder how should I wrap around something that raises an event.
So that I can extend those events as well but still be able to raise an event for apps that use my extended class. So it acts a bit like a passtrough with added functionality. Let me clarify this with a bit of code

So MyExtend class has this code fragment in its constructor

```
thirdpartyClass theirclass += new thirdpartyclass()
thirdpartyClass.init()
theirclass.EventX = += MyWrapper_Method
```

Then the wrapper for the event  inside MyExtend class look  like

```
Public Void MyWrappedEvent_method()
{
  messagebox("logged it") //it actually logs to a database but i keep it short here
}
```

Now some other program in the future should be able to use MyExtend class.
And be able to do other things besides logging it, when a certain events (ea MyWrappedEvent)  happens so that i could write

```
Using MyExtend;

//somwhere in main     
MyExtend HasExtended = new MyExtend();
HasExtended.MyWrapper += NewFutureRoutine()
//...
// ..

public void NewFutureRoutine()
{
  //when i call this event i wont need to care about logging thats allready in it
  // so i could focus on other tasks ea:
  Arduino.Controller(setHardwarePin,high);
}
```

Comment: I guess you will need to catch the event in your wrapper, then fire it again.

Comment: well above code allready catches it, but thats inside the MyExtend class, i wonder how to re- fire it (expose as event) from there

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkzf914z(v=vs.90).aspx or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/how-to-raise-and-consume-events or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734700/how-to-manually-invoke-an-event

Comment: @PaulKaram if you post that as an Answer then i mark it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to let your `MyExtend` class handle the events, you will need to catch the desired event in your class, then fire another event and subscribe to it.
I would recommend to read and follow the following links/instructions:

[Raising an Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkzf914z(v=vs.90).aspx)
[How to: Raise and Consume Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/how-to-raise-and-consume-events)
[How to manually invoke an event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734700/how-to-manually-invoke-an-event)