# Declare a static event in an interface and raise in the implementation

Tags: c#

```
public interface IProgress
{
    public static event Action<IProgress> EvtSpawned;
}
```

```
public class PlayerSingle : MonoBehaviour, IProgress
{
   
    private void Start()
    {
        IProgress.EvtSpawned?.Invoke(this);
    }
}
```

I basically want to be able to have some classes listen to whenever an instance is created that implements IProgress. I can subscribe to the event above, but it seems there is no way for me to raise it, it just throws an error even when using within a class that implements IPgrogress.

For now, I just use static events in classes that implement it one by one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? I think it's a duplicate essentially [How to manually invoke an event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734700/how-to-manually-invoke-an-event)

Answer (score 3):

Events can be invoked only by the "owners" i.e. `IProgress` interface in this case. Not sure why do you require such structure (the provided description is not enough for me) but if you really need to you can declare an invoke method on the interface to delegate the event invocation:

```cs
public interface IProgress
{
    public static event Action<IProgress> EvtSpawned;
    public static void Invoke(IProgress inv) => EvtSpawned?.Invoke(inv);
}

public class PlayerSingle :  IProgress
{
    private void Start()
    {
        IProgress.Invoke(this);
    }
}
```